# Correct way to remove Apple Watch Glance view from final build without deleting it from project?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-glances

Is there a way to make a app store build without WatchKit Glance view while project still have glance files so they can be used later?

All other related questions in Stackoverflow suggested deleting glance files, but I still want them in project to develop later. What is the best practice?

Comment: It's not like you have to completely erase the glance files from your hard disk, just remove them from the project.

Comment: @Thilo there should be a way to simply remove it from the build without even deleting any file at all. Isn't it?  Removing target membership might work but I don't have a real device to test this.

Comment: @Thilo and it's not possible to just remove files from project while they are still in hard disk. Storyboard holds all views and it's just a single file in hard disk.

Comment: Considering that watchOS 3 won't have glances, you might not want to plan to use them in a future build.